# Python : the best way to download big data from s3 bucket and compress

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have to download all the data from s3 and since it is huge size, i have to divide it and compress it so that I can save it in local. I am going to use flask-s3 package to download data, but I wonder how can I divide data and compress it. I am new to python, and I never done any work that need to compress data into zip file or whatever. Is there any good package or good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to download files stored in a S3 bucket, I don't see how [Flask-S3](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be of any help, since this project seems to help with *uploading* static assets to S3.

Alternatively, you can use boto3's S3 client to [download S3 files](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) and python's [gzip module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) to compress the downloaded files.